# Prove if $p\mid q$, then $p\leq |q|$ or $q=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove if $p\mid q$, then $p\leq |q|$ or $q=0$.
We have gone over the basic properties of $\mathbb{Z}$, the definition of $a\mid b$ for $a\neq 0$, and the Division Algorithm.

I started on with this for my proof: Assume $p\mid q$. Then if $q\neq 0$ we have $q=px$ for some $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I should start my proof with something else. I know intuitively that this fact is true, but I'm not positive on how to get there.

Comment: Looks like a candidate for proof by contradiction.  "Suppose there exist $p>q>0$ such that $p|q$"

Comment: If $x = 0$ then $q=0$.  If $q \ne 0$ then $x = \frac pq$ is an integer.  If $\frac pq$ is an integer what does that say about $|p|$ and $|q|$?   (Did you every notice that if $0 < a < b$ that $\frac ab$ seems to never be an integer.  Example $\frac 23$ is not an integer  $\frac {53792}{78358}$ is not an integer.  Did you ever wonder why?)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you have $q = px$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, either $q = 0$, in which case $x = 0$, or $q \neq 0$, so $x \neq 0$, giving

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
1 & \le |x| \\
|p| & \le |p||x| \\
p & \le |p| \le |q| \\
p & \le |q|
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not all proofs are deep (or elegant).

$p|q$ means there is an integer, $k$, so that $p*k = q$ which, if $q\ne 0$ means $\frac qp = k$ is an non-zero integer.

So $\frac {|q|}{|p|} = |k|$ is an non-zero positive integer.

If $|q| < |p| $ then $\frac {|q|}{|p|} < 1$ and is not an integer.  So $|q| \ge |p|$.

And so $-|q| \le  p \le |q|$.

That's all.